# Load testing using VSTS. Searching from a CSV file and then clicking on the first element

Tags: c#, visual-studio, csv, performance-testing, load-testing

I have a question regarding a performance/load testing scenario.

I understand that it's best practice not to combine more than one variable when doing a load test. However, the management is insisting on it.

Scenario: User searches for an item and then clicks on a specific item from the search results to bring up details in an i-frame.

Validation: Make sure the search is performant and the details open in the i-frame as expected- without crashing the i-frame.

I have recorded the scenario using VSTS. I am using a CSV file for the search criteria. However, how do I configure the test to click on the "first" element in the search results every time?

Thank you for very much, I apologize if I missed anything.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Please [edit] it to add lots more detail. The basic plan is to use an extraction rule on the response body (you might have to write your own) to get the first search response. Use the extracted value to replace the relevant part of the request that retrieves the wanted item from the search results. Note that a web performance test will not validate that the iframes etc are correct. You might add some validation rules to check them. Remember that web performance tests do not use the browser, they just send html requests and collect the responses.

Answer (score 0):

Correlate for the first returned item on the page.  You may have to post process the returned data.

You will likely find a POST operation which follows where the results of your selection are captured.  Once you have captured the data from the returned stream on the page, then use the captured data to replace the data in the post related to the item being queried.

You can also use this same captured data to validate the returned page contains the data that is expected, rather than potentially a random unrelated item, but which still returns an HTTP 200 as a valid page.   Search for the appropriate unique string in the returned page data to ensure that not only you have requested the proper page, but the page you expect is being returned.